# Loading data from sqllite database & printing to html element

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova, onload

I'm building a PhoneGap Android application and have an SQLLite DB loaded with Javascript. The database has loaded correctly and data presence proven.

I'm using JQuery Mobile Framework for the GUI. On one of the subpages of the app I am trying to load elements from the DB and print them out as list elements - I've been trying to do this with an 'onload=""' call in the opening list tag, however, no function is being called - tried doing this with a simple alert to ensure something is happening, but coming up with nothing.

Quiet happy to play with printing DB results myself, I'm just trying to get the function to call right now. Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
<div data-role="page" id="cachelist"> <!-- Start of cache list screen -->
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Cache List</h1>
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </header>
        <article data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="cachelistList" onload="alert('test')">

            </ul>
        </article>
</div> <!-- End of cache list screen -->
```

Here's the div - you can see I'm trying to call from the opening `<ul>`.

I've also tried calling to a JS function in the `<head>` of the document, I don't think that would make a difference - but it's below just in case it does.

```
<ul onload="cacheListPrint()">
</ul>


function cacheListPrint() {
    alert("Getting this far");
    db.transaction(queryDBPrint, errorCB);
}

function queryDBPrint(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM cache', [], querySuccessPrint, errorCB);
}

function querySuccessPrint(tx, results) {
    var rows = results.rows;
    var len = rows.length;
    if(len > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            document.getElementById('cachelistList').innerHTML += 
        '<li><h1>' + rows.item(i).name + '</h1></li>';
        }
    }
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ".pagebeforeshow". 
".pagebeforeshow" will be triggered on the new page before animation starts.

```
$( '#yourPageID' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    cacheListPrint();
});
```